# how to display all record (filter by name) into a form, Django

Tags: python, django, forms

im new to Django and i try to learn it. 
The critic point for me is a Form chapter!

My project has a class "charter" and i want to display all objects (by field name) into a dropdown menu!

and i want to create 2 anothers dropdown form for a particular "search" (by type and guest)

models.py

```
class Charter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    guest = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

the picture explains better...
https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-lJDVVEVRpJc/T2NHRphgdPI/AAAAAAAAAdk/By8oki041fI/w490-h500-k/Schermata%2B2012-03-16%2Ba%2B14.45.02.jpg

(sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 1):

In your forms.py, you can create what's called a ModelForm by doing:

```
class CharterForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
           model = Charter
```